# axis2.jar in websphere 8.5

Tags: java-8, apache-axis

I'm trying to install axis2.jar (1.7) in Websphere 8.5 which is using java 8. I have selected parent last in axis2.jar. Axis2 has some wsdls installed and it'll communicate with oracle 12c to retrieve data. In axis2 shared libraries i'm including xdb6, ojdbc7.jar. When i start to post an xml through SOAP UI, im getting the below error in WAS.

> "[7/30/18 11:19:04:368 EEST] 000000b7 IntegrationLa E
>   'IntegrationLandscapeService' is currently not availble OR does not
>   exist - RuntimeException : Error creating bean with name
>   'IntegrationLandscapeServiceImpl' defined in class path resource
>   [integrationLandscapeServiceContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
>   instantiate bean class
>   [com.temenos.services.integrationlandscape.IntegrationLandscapeServiceImpl]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint violation when overriding
>   method
>   "**java/sql/SQLXML.getSource(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljavax/xml/transform/Source;"
>   during creation of class "oracle/xdb/XMLType": loader
>   "com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@924d5a69" of class
>   "oracle/xdb/XMLType" and loader
>   "com/ibm/oti/vm/BootstrapClassLoader@e7afefce" of class
>   "java/sql/SQLXML**" have different types for the method signature"

Oracle.xdb.XMLType is loaded from xdb6.jar and other applications using this xdb6.jar is working fine without issues. But when used from axis2.jar its creating the above error.

Can someone help me or shed some light on this since i couldnt figure out the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use an isolated class loader. When you configure you shared lib check the "Use an isolated class loader for this shared library".